# Submit drop down on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a list of pages generated by Wordpress within a drop down, on click, how can submit the form and goto the page that was selected?

```
<form id="work" action="" method="post">
<select name="work">
    <?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => '15', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order')); 
    foreach($pages as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $fields = get_fields(); ?>
        <option class="work-dropdown" value="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></option>    
    <?php } wp_reset_query(); ?> 
</select>           
</form>
```

I tried this jquery but I'm not sure if that's correct and what to put in the action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$('.work-dropdown').change(function() {
  $('#work').submit();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What jQuery have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to redirect the page try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $('select[name="work"]').change(function(){
        window.location = $(this).val();
    })
});
</script>
```

You may want to add an ID to the select to make the jQuery selector faster.
So you would add: `id="page-redirect"` to the select change the jQuery object to `$('#page-redirect')`. ID's are selected much faster than classes or attributes.

If you want the form to post to the selected URL then try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#work select[name="work"]').change(function(){
        $('#work').attr('action', $(this).val()).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The selected page will be loaded but the form will not submitted.

Comment: Do you want the form to be submitted @Rob?

Comment: @iambriansreed It doesn't really matter as long as when they select something in the drop down it then goes straight to the page. Neither pieces of code seem to do anything when selecting something

Comment: @Rob Then use my first option. Your jQuery selector for dropdown is `.work-dropdown` but that class isn't used in the demo in your question. FYI. If you do use the first option you don't need form tags at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.work-dropdown').change(function () {
        $('#work').attr('action', $(this).val());
        $('#work').submit();
    });
});
```

Will do this

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything when changing the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

The `.change()` cannot be written on `option`'s selector as you've written. It needs to be the `select`. So, `$('[name=work]')` needs to be your selector.

Also, it looks like your link is present in the value of the option. The below code should work.

```
$('[name=work]').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

EDIT:

You cannot do submit & then redirect to the page if you're resetting the dropdown on submit. In case, you need to submit and you didn't reset the dropdown & then redirect based on the URL or index,

```
$('[name=work]').change(function() {
    $('#work').submit();
});
//handle it on document ready & assuming your index's first option is plain text 'Select from below'
if($('[name=menu] :selected').index() > 0)
{
    window.location = $(this).val();
}
```

Comment: This will not submit the form

Comment: @Krishna It went to a new page but had "undedefined" after the link.