# Drop Down list without a submit button. how?

Tags: php

//  Is it possible to submit a form after just selecting an option in a dropdown list?

```
<select name="Search4">
                <option value="">--select--</option> 
                <option value="Director">Director</option>
                <option value="Architect">Architect</option>
                <option value="Sales Manager">Sales Manager</option>
                <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>   
</select>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638254/submit-drop-down-on-click

Comment: I believe this is what you are searching for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231157/how-to-submit-form-on-change-of-dropdown-list

Answer (score 3):

yes, with javascript (onchange). example:

```
            <select name="Search4" onchange="$('#myform').submit();">
            <option value="">--select--</option> 
            <option value="Director">Director</option>
            <option value="Architect">Architect</option>
            <option value="Sales Manager">Sales Manager</option>
            <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>   
            </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done by giving `id` to `select` and `form` in HTML and then on change of the select box you can call the form submit method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectboxID").change(function() {
     $("#formID").submit();
  });
});
```

for more about the `submit()` refer [**this**](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using jquery
first in your page add jquery libarary
after write following

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(#yourid).change(function(){
$(#myform).submit();


});



});

</script>



 <form id="myform" >
    <select name="Search4" id="yourid">
                    <option value="">--select--</option> 
                    <option value="Director">Director</option>
                    <option value="Architect">Architect</option>
                    <option value="Sales Manager">Sales Manager</option>
                    <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>   
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can do.
add a event into `select tag`

`<select onsubmit="">`

```
<select name="Search4" onsubmit="myFunction()">
                <option value="">--select--</option> 
                <option value="Director">Director</option>
                <option value="Architect">Architect</option>
                <option value="Sales Manager">Sales Manager</option>
                <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>   
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

on change of your dropdown submit the form.

try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select[name=Search4]").change(function(){

        $("#yourFormId").submit();
    })

});
```